# How should I predict the next h days using LSTM?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

Say I have a series of 100 days 1, 2, ..., 100 and time steps 3. How should I create my validation set to predict 3 days ahead if I don't have the true data for day 101, 102 and 103? The training set is [t-3, t-2, t-1] where t=[3, 100] as shown below:

```
X        Y
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5
...
97 98 99 100
```

I think of iteratively adding predicted value to the data for every prediction:

```
iter=1
X            Y_pred
98  99  100  101

iter=2
X            Y_pred
99  100  101 102

iter=3
X            Y_pred
100 101 102  103
```

Is it valid to do so or are there better solutions to this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I create my validation set to predict three days ahead if I don't have the true data for day 101, 102 and 103?

The loss, in your case, mean square error or other similar losses, is calculated by using the true labels and the predicted labels. It would not be correct to substitute one for the other. This holds for training and evaluation.

Therefore, the only option is to drop the labels after timestep 97. If you have a small dataset and prefer to minimize the dropping of the labels, you can mask out the loss calculated for the timesteps that lack the true labels. For example, in time step 99, you can use the loss of step 100, but you have to ignore the loss for steps 101 and 102.